# Проблема вывода переменных класса

Tags: ооп, php

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема.

```
class NameClass {
    private $mysql_user;
    private $mysql_pass;
    private $mysql_host;
    private $mysql_db;

    function returnTest() {
    echo $this->mysql_user;
}
}
```

Затем в index.php

```
include 'NameClass.php';
$core = new NameClass('root', 'test', 'localhost', 'blog');
$core->returnTest();
```

В итоге у меня пустая страница. Почему?

Comment: А где собственно сам конструктор?) Либо в пхп они какие-то хитрые?

Comment: неправильно выразился я :)

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич, нет, серьёзно, где конструктор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class NameClass
{
        private $mysql_user;
        private $mysql_pass;
        private $mysql_host;
        private $mysql_db;
function __construct($mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_host, $mysql_db)
    {
        $this->mysql_user = $mysql_user;
        $this->mysql_pass = $mysql_pass;
        $this->mysql_host = $mysql_host;
        $this->mysql_db = $mysql_db;
    }
// остальной код
}
```